# what is the purpose of support files in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have installed MySQL 5.6.17 on my Ubuntu 14.04 following the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-installation.html.

The instructions says to use the optional command :

```
shell> cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
```

But I do not see any "my-medium.cnf" file in the folder.

The instructions also mentions :

```
shell> cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server
```

What exactly is the purpose of copying this file to the destination?

Comment: [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask

Comment: i wonder what this does, what a `apt-get install mysql-server-5.6` dont.

Comment: wrong, the right place would be http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Conceptual questions go into programmers, don't they?

Comment: Sorry if i got the wrong forum. But I did not intend my question to be conceptual. I am trying to complete my MySQL setup, but i found these instructions to be confusing.

Comment: You should use the manual version that matches your actual version (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-installation.html)

Comment: Please close/delete this question, since you have now asked it at the right location (http://serverfault.com/questions/595024/what-is-the-purpose-of-support-files-in-mysql)

Comment: @asprin - no, Programmers is most certainly not a better place. Please read the help centre documentation of a site before telling people that it is a better destination. Better yet - tell **them** to read it before they post there.

Comment: Please accept my apologies. I am attempting to close the question now as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `my-medium.cnf` with `my.cnf` ,Because you use data directory and base directory at some where.MySQL need a path to access those directories.So inorder to make this changes you have to work with .cnf files.So it is understandable that you can make a copy of it.Before you edit.